# Is there any Other way to declare variable "var cloption = '<%= cloption %>'; "?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, variables, var

Is there any other way to declare the variable in jsp/ java script?

`var abc = '<%= abc %>';`

Comment: Why? What's wrong with that declaration? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, thanks for your response, instead of abc getting input like ```<script>alert(5019)</script>``` this. So i want to restrict getting this

Comment: Ok, but I still don't understand what's wrong with doing it the way you did in your question. What do you mean you want to restrict getting this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no other way to do it in the jsp file, but you can try to create the js code in the servlet (Java File).

Servlet:

```
String myJavaVariable = "StackOverflow";
request.setAttribute("myJavascript", "var abc="+myJavaVariable);
```

JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ${myJavascript}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want in JSP file only. here the piece of code in JSP file.
 ```var abc = '<%= abc %>';
   if(abc == "cpinsvc")  
   var clType = "S";```

while doing vulnerable testing value is change like this. ```var abc = '<script>alert(5019)</script>';
   if(abc == "cpinsvc")  
    htfile = "w4ecpinsvc.ht";
   var clType = "S";```
Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Anitha the problem is not with how you show the variable, but the fact that you're probably sending a user-supplied value directly to the page without any validation or sanitization. In other words, you're looking at the wrong place to solve the problem.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, May be your correct, Actually I need to sanitize the input in JSP file. In other words prevent the DOM based cross site scripting. By using this URL this file is accessing file name query.jsp actual file ```http://rss.mt.att.com:8001/w4eqry/query.jsp``` but hacker are manipulating like this ```http://rss.mt.att.com:8001/w4eqry/query.jsp?option=insvcssclcid&cloption=%3Cscript%3Ealert(5019)%3C/script%3E```.

Comment: That's another question entirely. Now that I pointed you in the right direction you should do your own research on how to treat your inputs (see [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) for example) and then, if you have further doubts, open another question.